# How can i invoke my methods before and after mtd annotated by @Step?

Tags: java, junit, allure

I'd like to make screenshots before and after steps of my tests.

How can i make this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your question.

Allure java adaptor has undocumented feature - [Lifecycle listener](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-core/blob/master/allure-java-adaptor-api/src/main/java/ru/yandex/qatools/allure/experimental/LifecycleListener.java)

Lifecycle listener uses [Java SPI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/SPI-intro.html)

To solve your problem just add the following class to your classpath

```
public class EachStepScreenshoter extends LifecycleListener {

    @Override
    public void fire(StepStartedEvent event) {
        takeScreenshot();
    }

    @Override
    public void fire(StepFinishedEvent event) {
        takeScreenshot();
    }

    @Attachment(value="A screenshot")
    private byte[] takeScreenshot() {
        //Return screenshot content
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!
Very cool future, but don't work.
Should i make some chenges in pom.xml?

Comment: Add META-INF/services/ru.yandex.qatools.allure.experimental.LifecycleListener file to your resources with name of your listener. Read more about Java SPI

Comment: There are only one problem - fire(StepFinishedEvent) running *after* step finished, screenshot will be attached to parent step/test

Comment: Sample usage of lifecycle listener https://github.com/allure-examples/allure-java-lifecyclelistener-example

Comment: Tnx! Your drug helps.
I wish to annotate `public void fire(StepFailureEvent event){..}` by @Step. It will create a step in report with my comment.
What do you think about this idea?

Comment: Don't see a problem at all

Answer (score 0):

There's no particular solution for that. Allure uses AspectJ to intercept method calls and check for annotations present. As you know **@Attachment** annotation on any method returning byte[] can be used to take screenshot. So I would define such annotation method and call it where necessary:

```
@Attachment(value="A screenshot")
private byte[] takeScreenshot() {
    //Return screenshot content
}

@Step
private void myStep() {
    takeScreenshot();
    //Step logic
    takeScreenshot();
}
```